# jquery - not able to display the needed content with the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have this jQuery script that I do not fully understand. I was wondering why I cannot replace the siblings('div') with a class or id? I think my code doesn't work properly. What I was trying to do is replace some content with a button click, and then the second content, replace it again with the second function.
All courses get replaced by faculties, but faculties dont get replaced by the departments, when I press on a department, they all show one under another

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btnClick').on('click', function() {
    var faculty_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + faculty_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
  });
  $('.btnClick2').on('click', function() {
    var department_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + department_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h4>Search courses</h4>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <ul>
        <li class="btnClick" id="fac_1">Faculty of Mathematics and Informatics</li>
        <ul>
          <li class="btnClick2" id="dep_1">Mathematics and Informatics</li>
          <ul>
            <li>Informatics</li>
            <li>Mathematics</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
        <li class="btnClick" id="fac_2">Faculty of Medicine</li>
        <ul>
          <li class="btnClick2" id="dep_2">Medicine</li>
          <ul>
            <li>Medical Sciences</li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div>
        <h3>All courses</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=artificial-intelligence>Artificial Intelligence</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=software-engineering>Software Engineering</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=surgery>Surgery</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="fac_1_tab" style="display:none;">
        <h3> Faculty of Mathematics and Informatics courses</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=artificial-intelligence>Artificial Intelligence</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=software-engineering>Software Engineering</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="fac_2_tab" style="display:none;">
        <h3> Faculty of Medicine courses</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="first" href=surgery>Surgery</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <div id="dep_1_tab" style="display:none;">
          <h3>Department of Mathematics and Informatics courses</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="first" href=artificial-intelligence>Artificial Intelligence</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="first" href=software-engineering>Software Engineering</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <div id="dep_2_tab" style="display:none;">
          <h3>Department of Medicine courses</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a class="first" href=surgery>Surgery</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is also the full code in django if helps: https://pastebin.com/y9tHNbax

Comment: By clicking on faculty name it replaces all courses with the courses specific to that faculty. I want to do same thing for my departments, so when I click on a department name, that specific department courses will show. The courses show also for department, but the faculty courses will not go hidden.

Comment: why it is accepted? by partially working answer

Comment: She edited the script. Check it.

Comment: in that code when click department then facility courses gone away. check it https://jsfiddle.net/saw55fn8/3/

Comment: check answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question 
but you can try this

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnClick').on('click', function () {
            $('.col-md-9').find('[id^="dep"]').hide()
            var faculty_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + faculty_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();

        });
        $('.btnClick2').on('click', function () {
            $('.col-md-9').find('[id^="fac"]').hide()
            $('.col-md-9').find('[id^="dep"]').hide()
            var department_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + department_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is partially working, because department will show for each faculty. But I just want that faculty will not show when department shows.

Comment: I modified it accordingly and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: That is my pleasure

Comment: why it is accepted? This is partially working not all

Answer (score 2):

Department cannot replace each other because they are not siblings. they are exist different `ul`. if all Department are same `ul` it work proparly

check it. it works as your need

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/saw55fn8/4/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btnClick').on('click', function () {
    $('.col-md-9').find('[id^="dep"]').hide()
        var faculty_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + faculty_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
    });
    $('.btnClick2').on('click', function () {
        var department_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#fac_' + department_id.split('_')[1] + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
        $('#' + department_id + '_tab').show().siblings('div').hide();
    });
});
```